# async/await server process that happens to use WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I want to build a process which is continuously running, and continuously doing various work on various threads.  Async/await seemed to be a good way to go for that sort of thing.

I also want it to be able to accept commands from other processes which will affect the way it does that work.  Named pipes seemed like a good way to go for that particular piece of the puzzle, and named pipes via WCF seemed nicer than just raw named pipes.

But now I'm struggling to combine the two - an async/await environment that happens to use WCF.  Googling around for things like "wcf async await" has thus far only revealed stuff like [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html), which seems to be an entirely different issue (how to make async/await WCF service contracts, using [AsyncPattern=true]).  What I'm instead trying to figure out is what exactly I do in my Main (or Main-equivalents, e.g. Onstart/OnStop in a Windows Service) to get a WCF service host up and running (and later shut down), and allowing that WCF service to affect another (pre-existing, long-running) thread, all in the world of async/await.

So for example, forgetting about async/await for a moment, here's a simple console app that starts up a WCF service, waits for console input, and shuts down:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyServiceHostFactory factory = new MyServiceHostFactory(new Writer());

    using (ServiceHost host = factory.CreateMyServiceHost(
    new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
    {
        var pipeBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        pipeBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            typeof(IMyService),
            pipeBinding,
            "asdfMyService");

        host.Open();
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

The "new Writer()" stuff is just a proof-of-concept for injecting something into the WCF service implementer; in reality I'd be injecting something that the WCF service implementer could use to tell a long-running thread to somehow adjust its behavior.

I am totally new to async/await, and I am unsure how to do something equivalent to the above in the async/await world.  My vague thought is "start up two tasks, one of which reads the console and sets a cancellation token when complete, the other of which starts up the WCF service host and then shuts it down when the cancellation token is triggered".  But... how?

I can't help but imagine using Task.Run, but I keep seeing articles like [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html) which seem to indicate "Yeah, that's what noobies always think, and it's wrong."  But what's right, here? The "proper approach", according to the quoted article, is "to change the blocking call to an asynchronous call first and then allow async to grow from there".  But the example (and other examples I've seen online) is just a simple "Task.Delay rather than Thread.Sleep" sort of thing.  It doesn't make it clear to me what to do in this seemingly more complex WCF service situation.

Bonus complication: Stuck on .Net 4.0.

Comment: What exactly is that problem that you are trying to solve with async/await?

Comment: Yacoub Massad, I want a long-running server process that is continuously doing various work in various threads.  What I have read has led me to perhaps mistakenly conclude that async/await is the modern way to multithreading/concurrency/the like.

Comment: Continue to use tasks. Use async/await on IO method calls (read from disk, network, etcetera) to let your server scale better. Let passive tasks (invoked by other tasks) implement a thread-safe queue (a BlockingCollection is nice here) so that they can pass messages to each other for processing. This is much better than method calls which easily creates deadlocks and race conditions.

Comment: Frode, thank you, but my question is more specifically: In the world of async/await, what do I do in Main (or a Main-like thing) to set up and eventually tear down a WCF service.  I think I can handle getting info back and forth from the WCF service to other threads, once all of them are up and running; I'm just not sure what to do to get it and the other threads up and running in the first place (in the async/await world).